# Armazenar uma imagem dentro de uma variável javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Fla galera.. alguém sabe se há como armazenar diretamente numa variável javascript uma imagem ?

***exemplo na função abaixo***

```
function saudacao(obj) {
    var data = new Date();
    var hora = data.getHours();
    var txt = "";
    // ideia de variavel armanezando imagem 
    var variavelFoto = "img/imagem.png"

    if (hora < 12) {
        txt = "BOM DIA !" + variavelFoto;

    } else if (hora < 18) {
        txt = "BOA TARDE !" + variavelFoto;
    } else {
        txt = "BOA NOITE !" + variavelFoto;
    }

    // aqui abaixo ele insere o valor da variavel txt na div "saudacao" 
    document.getElementById("saudacao").innerHTML = txt;

}
```

Comment: desculpe mas pq precisaria fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da maneira que está querendo fazer, usando a propriedade `innerHTML`, uma maneira é construir uma tag `<img>` e armazena-la dentro de sua variável `variavelFoto`.

```js
function saudacao(obj) {
    var data = new Date();
    var hora = data.getHours();
    var txt = "";

    // Cria uma tag <img> com a imagem que quer exibir e guarda em variavelFoto 
    var variavelFoto = '<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/smiley-face-cartoon-260nw-67126804.jpg" height="42" width="42" style="vertical-align: middle;">';

    // como todos as versões de txt terão variavelFoto adicionado ao final retirei o trecho + variavelFoto; das verificações;
    if (hora < 12) {
        txt = "BOM DIA !";

    } else if (hora < 18) {
        txt = "BOA TARDE !";
    } else {
        txt = "BOA NOITE !";
    }

    // aqui abaixo ele insere o valor da variavel txt na div "saudacao" dentro de um span e adicionei o variavelFoto que retirei das verificações acima.
    document.getElementById("saudacao").innerHTML = '<span style="vertical-align: middle;">' + txt + '</span>' + variavelFoto;

}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="saudacao()">Saudação!</button>
<div align="center" id="saudacao"/>
```

Comment: deu certinho!!! show de bola!!!!!!!!!!