# Erro ao mudar a imagem JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

A imagem não está mudando dependendo da hora:

```
function charge() {
  var msg = window.document.getElementById('msg')
  var img = window.document.getElementById('photo')

  var date = new Date()
  var hour = date.getHours()
  var minutes = date.getMinutes()

  msg.innerHTML = `Agora são ${hour} horas e ${minutes} minutos`
  if (hour >= 0 && hour < 12) {
    img.src = 'manha.png'
  } else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 18) {
    img.src = 'tarde.png'
  } else {
    img.src = 'noite.png'
    console.log(hour)
  }
}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Armazenar uma imagem dentro de uma variável javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/403288/armazenar-uma-imagem-dentro-de-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-javascript)

Comment: Não, por conta de ser mais imagens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, tem algumas considerações a se fazer sobre seu código:

**HTML**

```
<div id = 'msg'></div>
<br />
<img id = 'photo' />
```

Aqui em javascript você declarou a função, porém esqueceu de chamar ela, que nesse caso, era apenas `charge();`.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function charge() {
  var img = window.document.getElementById('photo');
  var msg = window.document.getElementById('msg');

  var date = new Date();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();

  msg.innerHTML = `Agora são ${hour} horas e ${minutes} minutos`
  if (hour < 12) {
    img.src = 'https://meuprimeiroape.blog.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/sol-manha.jpg';
  } else if (hour <= 18) {
    img.src = 'https://cdn.mensagenscomamor.com/content/images/p000007513.jpg?v=0';
  } else {
    img.src = 'https://www.eusemfronteiras.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Capturar.png';
  }
}

charge();
```

Como indicado pelo Augusto Vasques, também tem comparações desnecessárias, sendo que a primeira condição `hour < 12` se não estiver correta, já elimina a possibilidade de ser de manhã, a segunda condição verifica se é de tarde, sendo `hour <= 18` não sendo mais redundante a opção da manhã na comparação e por fim, caso não satisfazendo essas condições, finaliza como noite.

> Veja o código funcionando:
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/2reugtxj/

Comment: Concordo com você, irei alterar minha resposta. Muito obrigado.